# Gamecenter Matchmaking Doesn't Work

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, gkmatchmaker

Here is my Menu.m's onEnter method:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 2;
GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

tempVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:tempVC.view];
[tempVC presentModalViewController: mmvc animated: NO];
mmvc.view.frame = CGRectMake(150, 150, 510, 420);
```

I tried with device and simulator but they couldn't match.

I also tried it to do by following Ray Wenderlich's [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12):

But then, even matchmakerviewcontroller didn't show up. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Testing GameKit on simulator causes a lot of trouble. I'm afraid you will need 2 devices to test your game.

Comment: I am successfully testing my app with once device and the simulator. The only shortcoming I have found with the simulator is that it does not automatically catch match updates from the game center like a real device. I have to manually view the game center match status to see when it is my turn on the simulator.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using two different game center IDs -- one for your simulator and one for your device?

Is your device logged into the game center sandbox?

The simulator will use the game center sandbox, and your device must also use the sandbox for the two to connect.

You can log into the game center sandbox by logging out of the game center, and then starting your app. Your app should ask you to log into game center. Performing the login through your non-released app will put you in the game center sandbox.